# Can we copy files from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) of Build server to a Azure Iaas server using Agent Pool “Hosted VS2017”

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We are using CI/CD pipeline in OneITVSO. Earlier we had an agent pool which was internally created. Now we are asked to use "Hosted VS 2017". We have a Database solution, ETL solution and Tabular Model solution that needs to get deployed. Additionally we have certain scope scripts.

We are able to build the solution using "Hosted VS 2017". But we are not able to deploy using "Hosted VS 2017" In the release pipeline we have a task "Windows Machine File Copy" which copies either artifacts/dacpac/ispac/.sql files from build server to dev/uat servers.

Using the earlier agent pool this pipeline was getting deployed successfully. But now when we use "Hosted VS 2017" we are getting below error:
**Failed to connect to the path \DEVSERVERSQL01 with the user *domain\servicecredentialdwd* for copying. System error 53 has occurred.**

1) Can "Hosted VS 2017" be used for task like "Windows Machine File Copy" (We are using Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine(Iaas) )

2) If we can use "Hosted VS 2017" even for Iaas Azure machines, are we missing any credential access. Should we give any access to domain\servicecredentialdwd for the agent pool "Hosted VS 2017". If so what permissions has to be given and how.

Answer (score 1):

The hosted agents are run on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine, you don't have access from hosted agent to your private local network.

So if you want to deploy to your on-premise servers you must use a private agent and not the 
Azure DevOps Hosted Agent.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong info. We are using Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine(Infra as a service). Its not on-premise. Have corrected my main question . Can you please let me know if we can use "Windows Machine File Copy" for Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine using “Hosted VS2017”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Hosted VS 2017 agents/Pool with your "Windows File Copy" to copy files to the VMs running in Azure.